# What's the "grade" in "make the grade"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-origin

***[Make the grade](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+grade)*** is an idiomatic AmE expression meaning:

> - Satisfy the requirements, qualify; also, succeed. *For example, Angela hoped her work in the new school would make the grade, or Barbara certainly has made the grade as a trial lawyer.*

According to  *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*,  this expression uses grade in the sense of "accepted standard." [c. 1900].

***[The Indu](http://www.thehindu.com/books/know-your-english/know-your-english-meaning-and-origin-of-make-the-grade/article4917973.ece)*** offers an alternative meaning of grade:

> - In American English, ‘grade’ is also used to refer to a gradient or a slope. In the context of the idiom, it refers to the steep incline a train has to climb. A train that makes the grade is one that is successful in climbing a steep incline or slope.

and a similar interpretation is given by [The Dictionary of American Slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make--the--grade)

> - 1912+; perhaps from a train's ability to climb up the grade or slope of the track.

Questions:

- Is there more solid evidence of what "grade" refers to? If the "train" story is true, I guess the expression was probably popular in train/railways related contexts, at least in its earliest usages. Is there any evidence in that respect?

Comment: According to the Online Etymology Dictionary (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grade): "To figuratively _make the grade_ 'be successful' is from 1912; early examples do not make clear whether the literal grade in mind was one of elevation, quality, or scholarship."

Comment: @ConnorHarris - thanks, doubts on its meaning still persist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do 'stay on the list', 'make the list' and 'make the cut' all have the same meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9468/do-stay-on-the-list-make-the-list-and-make-the-cut-all-have-the-same-mean)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Duplicate? Did you read the question? Does the "original" question answer mine in some way?

Comment: OED's second cite for **grade** = *A step or stage in a process; rarely specifically a step in preferment* is from 1798: *W. Taylor in Monthly Mag. 6 553* - "He was a skilful pupil, and had attained the highest grade of initiation". The AmE sense **grade = gradient** (inclination to the horizontal) wasn't recorded until 1835.

Comment: I had always assumed *grade* originally referred to a sailor's position; *grade* remains the military term for what civilians call *rank*.

Comment: Since the expression is AmE, why isn't The American Heritage Dictionary good enough??? Here, it's standard, not slope.

Comment: @Lambie - well, I cited two AmE sources, with different views. Who's right?

Comment: @Josh The American Heritage has  more clout than either of the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This phrase appeared occasionally in non-metaphorical use<sup>1</sup> before the twentieth century, but took off in popularity throughout the 1920s and 30s:

[image: Google Ngram showing results for "make the grade", case insensitive. The all lowercase version appears below the 0.000001% level until approximately 1905, when it begins to rise. The slope quickly becomes steeper, rising very fast through the 1920s and 1930s to a peak of about 0.00024% in 1945. From there it falls unevenly (steeply until 1950, more gradually until 1960, and then slightly less steeply than its original rise) until 1990, when it reaches a low of just over 0.000008%. After that there is a slight rise again until the data ends in 2000.]

—[Google Ngram, "make the grade", case insensitive](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20the%20grade&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmake%20the%20grade%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmake%20the%20grade%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMake%20the%20Grade%3B%2Cc0)

Looking at early examples in Google Books, I think the "climb the hill" version is more likely, but I believe it took off in popularity not just from the train usage but also from individuals' personal experience trying to get buggies and, crucially to the time period of the phrase's largest gain in usage, from automobiles. From a 1917 publication (bolding mine):

> [After describing the health hazards of modern living:] The human machine is spoiled in the making. When you start to **take the grade** in it your motor heats, your spark plug misses, your carburetor gums and won't work, you blow out a tire, then you are shunted to the side of the road, or you tumble back to the level from which you started and there you remain—couldn't **make the grade**; you are an old worn-out, broken-down wreck with a sign pinned to you—"For Sale, Cheap"—just like the wreckage of wagons and buggies that you see in blacksmith shops all over the country.
>
> A wave of pity sweeps over me every time I see a derelict, human or machine—"could not **make the grade**" is stamped all over such relics.
> . . .
> Ninety per cent of men and women, normal in mind and healthy in body, can **make the grade, can climb the hills** if they are properly trained in childhood, and are taught the great laws of life.
> —[Charles Virgil Mosby, *Making the Grade*, 1917](https://books.google.com/books?id=PlJHAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22can%20make%20the%20grade%22&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=%22can%20make%20the%20grade%22&f=false)

This early adopter of the metaphor was clearly thinking in terms of hill climbing, rather than grades of wood (another early literal use of the term). It isn't clear to me whether the signs saying "could not make the grade" on wrecks were an actual phenomenon or just the author's imagining, but if it was an actual practice to put such signs on wrecks this would be a very strong, everyday visual reinforcement of the metaphor, even for non-drivers.<sup>2</sup>

Another early example of *make the grade* in the hill sense comes from an account of a 1920 Connecticut Republican gubernatorial primary convention<sup>3</sup>:

> The Roraback machine, after skipping and skidding through the night, failed to **make the grade** today and J. Henry Roraback, boss of Connecticut the last eight years, was visibly nervous as he sat on the platform behind the Permanent Chairman, United States Senator George P. McLean, watching the delegates whom he once completely controlled, break away and follow their own inclinations.
> —["Lake for Governor of Connecticut", *New York Times*, Special to The New York Times, Sept. 10, 1920.)](https://search.proquest.com/docview/98150896)

Here we have an extended metaphor equating a party's [political "machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_machine) failing to nominate a candidate to a train that tries to climb a steep grade, only to fail and see its cars (here, delegates) "break away". The hill metaphor is complete with the double meaning of ["inclination"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inclination): "a person's natural tendency or urge to act or feel in a particular way" and simultaneously "the fact or degree of sloping" (Oxford Dictionaries).

One final clue that the "hill" use may be the primary origin: this usage is consistent with the use of unmodified "grade". That is, a vehicle itself does or does not "make the grade", but most early examples of the literal use of making the grade in reference to accepted standards specify a grade *of* something. For example:

> I am not condemning hand separators, but we cannot **make the grade *of butter*** from the hand separator cream; that is the trouble, as far as the machine is concerned, the machine is all right.
> —[*Proceedings of the Tenth Annual Meeting of the Pennsylvania Dairy Union*, January 14-16, 1908](https://books.google.com/books?id=thjaAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22cannot%20make%20the%20grade%22&pg=RA3-PA15#v=onepage&q=%22cannot%20make%20the%20grade%22&f=false)

But

> They open up the throttle and give the train more speed in order to **make the grade**.
> —[Metz v. C. & W. C. Ry. Co., 125 S.C. 1, 1923 (*Reports of Cases Heard and Determined by the Supreme Court of South Carolina, Volume 125*); snippet view](https://books.google.com/books?id=JHAtAQAAMAAJ&q=%22make%20the%20grade%22&dq=%22make%20the%20grade%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD-Ymst6LWAhXh6oMKHcq9CxgQ6AEIRzAG)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Most of the earliest literal examples are actually about physically "making" a grade, i.e. earth-moving projects in road or railroad building to smooth, increase, or decrease slopes.  A few others refer to climbing hills, and a few show up as part of a larger clause/sentence or straddling two clauses/sentences about an accepted standard of something, e.g. a proposal for the grading of lumber to "Make the grade of No. 3 Common 33⅓ per cent and better clear instead of 25 per cent and better sound." ("Bell of Hardwood Institute on Low Grade Lumber Impasse", [*The Lumber Manufacturer and Dealer* Vol. 20, December 8, 1922](https://books.google.com/books?id=IEkcAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22make%20the%20grade%22&pg=RA22-PA9#v=onepage&q=%22make%20the%20grade%22&f=false))</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>It is also possible that this book itself or its author had some influence in the adoption of the metaphorical use of the phrase. I haven't been able to find out how successful the book was in its day, but it is still [available on Amazon as a "classic reprint"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1330522869); I don't know how these "classics" are selected, but there is at least a possibility that the book had a significant readership at one time. Moreover, Mosby was the founder of the eponymous academic publisher, which still exists as an Elsevier imprint (see [Wikipedia article "Mosby (imprint)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mosby_(imprint)&oldid=747528877)). I can imagine that a favorite metaphor of the founder of a publishing house might make it into the books of some of that publisher's books, and could trickle out from there.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>This database is paywalled; check with your local library for access to New York Times historical issues (most US libraries probably have access).</sub>

Comment: Very nice research, very good answer.

Comment: On a hunch, I checked when *The Little Engine that Could* was first mass distributed - 1920, as part of a set sold door-to-door in the US. It may not have been the origin, but it certainly provided a ready image to anyone over 5.

Comment: And *making the grade* was in railroad lingo. Locomotive Engineers Journal, Volume 29, p879, first column, 1895, from a speech by Mrs. Cassel - https://books.google.com/books/content?id=Jm1LAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA879&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U1oCNgkt013t-7ZsqEZ1G5fK_1irQ&ci=31%2C850%2C428%2C277&edge=0  The usage is highly metaphorical, comparing the role of the Ladies auxiliary to a tank engine.

Comment: Oh, nice find, @PhilSweet. Yes, the phrase was definitely in use for trains literally climbing hills, but that's the earliest example of figurative use I have seen.