# What is the meaning of "make all the lights"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "make all the lights" here?

> A: Do you think I will take more than 10 minutes going to the train station?
>   B:Well, if you want to get there in ten, you will have to **make all the lights**.

I know the meaning of "make light" but not "make all the lights".

Comment: Please cite your source. Try and include a link, too.

Comment: ...traffic lights.

Answer (score 6):

"Make all the lights" means not having to stop at any red lights throughout a trip. To "make a light" in this instance is to make it through an intersection without having to stop at a red light. So if you make all the lights, you won't have to stop at all, and you'll make good time!

In answer to Kris' question:

I don't have a reliable reference to be able to say decisively whether it's slang or an idiom. I don't know if it appears in respectable writing. It's often used in onscreen dialogue (e.g. [FullhouseS01E19](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=full-house&episode=s01e19), ninth line). And it has an entry in [Urban Dictionary](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Make%20the%20Light). Its usage is similar to other idioms (e.g. [Make-the-cut](http://collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-the-cut))

Comment: Is that an idiom? Is it slang? Is it some dialect of English? Are there use cases in respectable writing?

Comment: I added my response to this question in the original answer above.

Comment: I would call it an idiom.

Comment: Also @HotLicks If it's on UD, it's most likely slang. And UD is no authetic source to cite from on ELU, AFAIK.

Comment: @Kris - I didn't mention UD, but it's commonly cited here, and rarely is questioned.  But "make all the lights" I've been familiar with since I was a kid (and that was a looong time ago).

Answer (score 3):

To make the light means to drive through or go through (if someone else is driving) a traffic light when it is green or yellow.

To make all the lights means to do this for all the traffic lights on your way somewhere, or in a series of lights on one street.

I also don't have resources. It's not a major phrase used all the time, but I would say it's an idiom and is more slang than respectable. It's more often something we say than write, unless it's in a story of some kind. In writing a non-fiction description, you would write something like

"In order to arrive at place X from place Z in ten minutes, you/one must not be stopped at any of the traffic lights in between."

vs

"Well , if you want to get there in ten, you will have to make all the lights."

Answer (score 0):

This is *make* in the sense of reaching or attaining a location; as OALD has it:

> 18. [no passive] **make something** to manage to reach or go to a place or position
>
>     > *Do you think we'll make Dover by 12?*
>     >     *I'm sorry I couldn't make your party last night.*
>     >     *He'll never make* (= get a place in) *the team.  *
>     >     *The story made* (= appeared on) *the front pages of the national newspapers.*
>     >     *We just managed to make the deadline* (= to finish something in time).

To *make a light* in the example given refers to a traffic light, specifically to pass every traffic light on the route while it is green, by implication, without delay. I might have said *make all the greens*.

According to the OED, this is an extension of *make* in the broad sense of performing or accomplishing something. Related are the nautical use of *make* referring to achieving an intended destination (e.g. to *make port*, *make Liverpool*) or speed (*she'll make twenty knots*). You might need to leave early to *make your flight* (i.e. arrive at the airport in time to catch your flight), and hope you *[make the grade](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409847)* (or *make the cut*) at the job interview, and then you'll have *made it*—that is, achieved success, whether in life (*she's finally made it*) or in some challenge or task (*she's made it through boot camp*).

Comment: I'm only ever familiar with *make it to* (a place, an event, a destination), not with its breath saving-version *make*. And with *make* as in "make the grade". "She **made it through** the bootcamp", certainly not "She **made** the bootcamp".

Comment: @Kris I do say things like *we need to make Pittsburgh by noon*, but I'll grant that it's a little old-fashioned or literary, and *make it to Pittsburgh* is more common conversationally, likewise *we made it to every game* vs. *we made every game*. I wouldn't say she *made bootcamp* because bootcamp is a starting point, not a station or rank, but I do say things like *she made vice president at 30* all the time.